# check-in date with check-out date

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, jupyter-notebook

I'm on the jupyter notebook studying, and I created a problem that I can't solve
I have a dataframe with two columns with dates (already in datatime format)
column1 is the entry date
column2 is the departure date

how do I create a new column with the date range between column1 and column2?
In python

Comment: when you say data range, do you mean the number of days between dates in column1 and column2? Or do you want a list of dates between those two dates?

Comment: Can you share an example DataFrame and an expected output?

Comment: df
          A        B
one 2014-01-01  2014-02-28 
two 2014-02-03  2014-03-01

Answer (score 0):

Due to a lack of example `DataFrame`, I hacked together a random-generator of dates. Others, please feel free to use it to create a cleaner solution than me.

```
from random import randint
import datetime
import pandas as pd

date1 = datetime.date(2020,1,1).toordinal()
date2 = datetime.date(2021,1,1).toordinal()

dates = [sorted([randint(date1, date2), randint(date1, date2)]) for i in range(10)]

df = pd.DataFrame(dates, columns=["col1", "col2"])
df.col1 = df.col1.apply(lambda x: datetime.date.fromordinal(x))
df.col2 = df.col2.apply(lambda x: datetime.date.fromordinal(x))

df["col3"] = df.apply(lambda x: list(pd.date_range(start=x.col1, end=x.col2, freq="1D")), axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
         col1        col2                                               col3
0  2020-05-30  2020-07-04  [2020-05-30 00:00:00, 2020-05-31 00:00:00, 202...
1  2020-07-09  2021-01-01  [2020-07-09 00:00:00, 2020-07-10 00:00:00, 202...
2  2020-05-03  2020-10-20  [2020-05-03 00:00:00, 2020-05-04 00:00:00, 202...
3  2020-04-26  2020-06-29  [2020-04-26 00:00:00, 2020-04-27 00:00:00, 202...
4  2020-10-06  2020-11-03  [2020-10-06 00:00:00, 2020-10-07 00:00:00, 202...
5  2020-05-15  2020-12-22  [2020-05-15 00:00:00, 2020-05-16 00:00:00, 202...
6  2020-01-02  2020-02-06  [2020-01-02 00:00:00, 2020-01-03 00:00:00, 202...
7  2020-02-21  2020-09-28  [2020-02-21 00:00:00, 2020-02-22 00:00:00, 202...
8  2020-03-11  2020-07-29  [2020-03-11 00:00:00, 2020-03-12 00:00:00, 202...
9  2020-07-16  2020-07-18  [2020-07-16 00:00:00, 2020-07-17 00:00:00, 202...
```